# Get the current state of isSticky key in custom keyboard

Tags: android

I want to create a custom-keyboard that is just used in my app. I've done everything to make a simple custom-keyboard which just let me to type in some word. When I look around some tutorial about custom-keyboard on google and android docs, I see that the key can have this Attribute: android:isSticky, that makes a key to be a toggle-key.
But there is seem to be no way to get the current state of the toggle key.

[image: When the keyboard started]

[image: When you click on a toggle-key on the custom-keyboard, it will become like this:]

- So is there any way that I can get the state of the key that have the
  attribute android:isSticky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me ages to find this.  I stumbled across a solution almost out of desperation.

I'm sure there's a better way but this is how I did it:

```
List<Key> mKeyboardViewKeys = mKeyboardView.getKeyboard().getKeys();

for (Key k : mKeyboardViewKeys) {
  if ((k.code[0] == stickyKeyCode) && (k.on)) {

  // sticky key is ON

  }
}
```

I also managed to have the sticky key change colour by calling the `onPressed()` method and defining a drawable with a different colour in the `StateListDrawable` xml.

As I say.. there must be a better way but...